# constraint problems by updating Xcode 11.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, constraints

I was working on this view and everything was ok, I set the constraints in the right way. Now I have updated Xcode to 11.1 this happened:

[image]

Automatically moves the content to me... How do I fix it?

The code is this:

```
        //LEFTBUTTON
    self.prefixView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 80)];
    self.leftView = self.prefixView;
    self.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

    self.prefixView.delegate = self;
    self.prefixView.dataSource = self;
```

Comment: So the problem is this blue icon leaving your red rectangle frame, right?

Comment: @summerfinn3 no the problem is that the blue icon is placed all the way to the right instead of to the left ... it should be on the left side. using debug I see that it occupies almost the entire cell, the red I used for debugging .. is the prefixView

Comment: Prior to iOS 13, UITextField assumed that the frames of its leftView and rightView were correctly set when assigned and would never change. Starting in iOS 13, the implementation of leftViewRect(forBounds:)
 and rightViewRect(forBounds:)
 now ask the view for its systemLayoutSizeFitting(_:)
. To achieve the previous behavior when linking against and running on iOS 13, add explicit sizing constraints on the view, wrap it in a plain UIView, or subclass the view and implement systemLayoutSizeFitting(_